# jquery show/hide button to change tooltip

Tags: javascript, jquery, button, toggle

I have the jquery code below that changes the text in the button to show/hide but I would also like to change the tooltip/title when the button is hovered over with the mouse to also say show/hide

```
$('#HideShow').click(function()  
  {  
  if ($(this).text() == "Show")  
   {  
  $(this).text("Hide");  
    }  
   else  
  {  
  $(this).text("Show");  
   };  
   });
```

How can I use jquery to also change the tooltip/title to show/hide when the button is changed?

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#HideShow').click(function() {  
      if ($(this).text() == "Show") {  
          $(this).text("Hide").attr("title", "Hide");
       } else {  
          $(this).text("Show").attr("title", "Show");
       }
   });
```

Answer (score 0):

use the attr command

so `$(this).attr("attribute to change", "new value");`